# Javascript Toggle not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Javascript to look for "#mode2" in the URL and if so, it will produce a different colored image with canvas. That part of the script is working fine. The issue is in the script that produces the toggle hyperlink. It will toggle the first time correctly (which makes sense as its a different part of the script) and then will toggle either once or twice depending on where it starts.

I.E. Blue is the default, so if the page loads on blue, it will toggle orange and then back to blue and then won't work, where as if its on orange it will just toggle to blue and then won't work.

I know its probably some stupid error in my code but I can't find it so if someone could help me out I would appreciate it a lot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(blue){

if (blue == 0) {
blue = 1;
}
else if (blue == 1) {
blue = 0;
}
if (blue == 0){
var container = document.getElementById("navi");
            var content = '<a href="contact.html#mode1" title="toggle" onclick="toggle(blue);" >toggle colors</a> - <a href="index.html#mode2" title="home">back</a>';
            container.innerHTML= content;
}
else{
var container = document.getElementById("navi");
            var content = '<a href="contact.html#mode2" title="toggle" onclick="toggle(blue);" >toggle colors</a> - <a href="index.html" title="home">back</a>';
            container.innerHTML= content;

}

}

var pathArray = document.URL;
            if (pathArray.indexOf("mode2") != -1){
            var blue = 0;
var container = document.getElementById("navi");
            var content = '<a href="contact.html#mode1" title="toggle" onclick="toggle(blue);" >toggle colors</a> - <a href="index.html#mode2" title="home">back</a>';
            container.innerHTML= content;
}
else{
var blue = 1;
var container = document.getElementById("navi");
            var content = '<a href="contact.html#mode2" title="toggle" onclick="toggle(blue);">toggle colors</a> - <a href="index.html" title="home">back</a>';
            container.innerHTML= content;


}
</script>
```

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this (for all occurrences):

`onclick="toggle(blue);"`

do this:

`onclick="toggle('+blue+');"`

Here is a fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/YF4Nc/1/**

Comment: it worked, so thank you. can you explain why that works?

Comment: Scoping issue.  I'm not sure of the placement of all your code so I solved it that way which simply passes in the value `0` or `1` instead of the `blue` variable.  Another way to solve it is to make your `blue` variable global, just remove the `VAR` in front of it and don't pass it into the toggle function and it will work.  Here's an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/YF4Nc/8/** Since it will then be global, no matter where your links appear, they will have access to `blue` and it's current global value;